# Changing listView.sorting fires ItemCheckEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ListView which has checkboxes on the first column. While writing some code for a custom sort (when the user clicks the column header) I've come across some weird behavior.

When the user clicks a column header, I'm using a ColumnClickEventHandler to set listView.Sorting to SortOrder.Ascending (or SortOrder.Descending); when this line of code gets hit, it seems to fire off the ItemCheck event handler.

eg

```
listView.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(listView_ItemCheck);
listView.ColumnClick += new ColumnClickEventHandler(listView_ColumnClick);
...
...
void listView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
   // Determine whether the column is the same as the last column clicked.
   if (e.Column != sortColumn)
   {
      // Set the sort column to the new column.
      sortColumn = e.Column;
      // Set the sort order to ascending by default.
      listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
   }
   else
   {
      // Determine what the last sort order was and change it.
      if (listView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
         listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
      else
         listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
   }
}
```

After the line listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending; is hit the event handler for listView.ItemCheck is called.

Comment: listView or filesToSyncListView ?

Comment: I never did that sort of thing, but by pressing header, doesn't list select all columns and by that triggers selected event?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus apologies, I was simplifying the code for the example; they should have all read listView (now fixed in the OP)

Comment: @AleksandarToplek well, it doesn't hit the event handler unless I actually change the Sorting property; so I don't think it can be a question of focus.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Now that I think a bit, check state has probably not changed from last state so in listView_ItemCheck you could check if "checked" value has changed. Event is probably called but actually "check" value stays the same.

Comment: I tried to reproduce in a small console app, but was unable to get ItemCheck Event fired while Sorting. Could you maybe put a project sample anywhere ? I'd be interested...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I'll see what I can do, but unfortunately, a lot of the code base is proprietary

Comment: @HaemEternal I didn't even tried to reproduce your code but from what I think is the problem, solution would be this: [in listView_ItemCheck...] if (e.CurrentValue == e.NewValue) return;

Comment: @AleksandarToplek Thanks for the suggestion, I've given that a try, but it seems that when I click the column header, NewValue is CheckState.Checked and CurrentValue is CheckState.Unchecked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is probably a bad trick, but you could try :

```
void listView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
   listView.ItemCheck -= listView_ItemCheck;
   // Determine whether the column is the same as the last column clicked.
   if (e.Column != sortColumn)
   {

      // Set the sort column to the new column.
      sortColumn = e.Column;
      // Set the sort order to ascending by default.
      listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
   }
   else
   {
      // Determine what the last sort order was and change it.
      if (listView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
         listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
      else
         listView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

   } 
   listView.ItemCheck += listView_ItemCheck;
}
```

or

use a boolean property (`private bool disableItemCheck_`) used in

`listView_ColumnClick` (same place as my modifications) and

```
listView_ItemCheck 

if (disableItemCheck_)
return;
//ItemCheck logic
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't really get to the bottom of why it isn't working, but it does a perfect job of fixing the symptom.

Comment: However... the listView.ItemCheck -= listView_ItemCheck needs to go outside of the if else; as the two changes to Sorting in the else block will also kick off the event handler